# No way to add a view over a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer using StoryBoard?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, calayer, swift5

I have seen other questions about this on SO, but mine is different because I am looking for a solution using a structure previously created using storyboard.

I need to have a `StackView` over a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

I have a view like this:

[image]

I need to create a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in a way that puts this layer below the `Stack Control` you see on the previous picture.

My `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` WAS created like this:

```
let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
cameraPreviewLayer.frame = view.frame
view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
```

But to make sure the layer would be created at the current position, I've created this `Preview View` below `Stack Control` (see picture).

The idea is to add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to that view.

So, I changed the code to:

```
let cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
cameraPreviewLayer.frame = view.frame
previewView.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
```

have also tried

```
previewView.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer)
```

No way, the preview shows fine but `Stack Control` is not there. I see the stack if I do not insert the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is,

1. take AVCapturePreviewLayer, and add it as a sublayer to the PreviewView.

   PreviewView.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer)
2. Add previewView as a subView to the parent View

   view.addSubview(PreviewView)
3. and add StackControl as a subview to the parent View

   view.addSubview(StackControl)

Comment: In theory this is exactly what I am "doing", because every element is already at the "correct" level. As far as I see, you are saying that I must do that programmatically, right?

Comment: I think what you mean to say is that , in IB you already arranged everything in that same order. Right ? 
In that case can you take your application into debug mode -> and in a breakpoint check the view hierarchy to see if the stack controller is properly visible or not ?

Comment: Maybe there could be something wrong with the Stack Control ? Can you swap out that with a button or something simple just to check if that works fine ?